# background mode in xcode(swift)

Tags: swift

I am a beginner programmer(swift -ios 8)
how refresh my funtion in background(every 5second) in swift
What exactly do I need?

Thanks

Comment: show what you have done here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

        //add your function here which will run in background like fetching data from server 
})
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to run any function with fixed time interval you can use `NSTimer` this way:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: Selector("yourMethod"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And add its helper method:

```
//this will repeat on every 5 second
func yourMethod(){
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer
How do I refresh every 5 seconds?

Comment: If you want to refresh any function for every 5 second then use `NSTimer`

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again
After 5 seconds, and the program out ،class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate Be green

Comment: show me your crash log from console..

Comment: first >>16:56:52

after 5 sec>>(lldb)

Comment: It is not correct information. can you share your project?

Comment: replace `testtcpclient()` with `Selector("testtcpclient")` in your timer variable.and it will be: `var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("testtcpclient"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

Comment: Error again:((
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: show me that line you modified.

Comment: Don't add new answer but you can update your question..:)

Comment: ok 
I apologizeeeeeee

Comment: Bro your timer is working fine now there is a problem with your other code.

Comment: ok
In the background,refresh function every 5 seconds 
What solution do you propose?

Comment: Check out this sample project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=42948120348774970401

Comment: its good 
but i need call my funtion in backgroundmode

Answer (score -1):

```
    func testtcpclient(){

        var client:TCPClient = TCPClient(addr:"46.143.211.41", port:8080)

        var (success,errmsg)=client.connect(timeout: 1)
        if success{

            var (success,errmsg)=client.send(str:"AEBCD1" )
            if success{

                var data=client.read(1024*10)
                if let d=data{
                    if let str=String(bytes: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                        println(str)



                    }
                }
            }else{


                println(errmsg)
                var alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "no"
                alert.message = "no"
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("ok")
                alert.show()
            }
        }else{
            println(errmsg)
            var alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "no"
            alert.message = "no"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("ok")
            alert.show()
        }



    }


     var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("testtcpclient"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)




}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.